# GSON : How to convert Object (which itself contains JSON) to JSON

Tags: java, gson

I have a different use case where fields in POJO itself stores JSON data, basically grouping of all data.

Now i want the complete JSON generated from above POJO.

At present i am using this method

```
private static Gson gson = new Gson();
public static String convertObjectToJSON(Object object) throws Exception {
    String jsonResponse = gson.toJson(object);
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

But getting output with escape characters around double quotes like below

```
 { \"_id\" : 234242, \"name\" : \"carlos\"}
```

I tried various options in GsonBuilder, but not working.
Basically, i am just grouping multiple JSON data and sending it across.

Could you please do the needful help to get rid of the escape characters around double quotes.

#### UPDATE:

Question is : I have 3 JSONs and need to combine them into a single JSON and need to pass it to html5 client through Spring MVC. As of now i am added the 3 JSONs into a POJO and trying to convert the same to JSON. Same is explained above.

Thanks & Regards

Venkat

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below sample code and it doesn't have any escape characters around double quotes.

```
class MyPOJO{
    private int _id;
    private String name;
    // getter & setter
}

String json="{ \"_id\" : 234242, \"name\" : \"carlos\"}";
MyPOJOobj=new Gson().fromJson(json, MyPOJO.class);
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(obj));
```

output:

```
{"_id":234242,"name":"carlos"}
```

---

#### EDIT

If you want to combine 3 JSON string then It will be stored as List of object as illustrated below:

sample code:

```
String json = "[" +
                    " { \"_id\" : 1, \"name\" : \"A\"}," +
                    " { \"_id\" : 2, \"name\" : \"B\"}," +
                    " { \"_id\" : 3, \"name\" : \"C\"}" +
                "]";
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyPOJO>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<MyPOJO> obj = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(obj));
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "A"
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "B"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "C"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you Braj.The above solution is adding decimals to int which will cause froblems for my code. And also my question is i have 3 json strings, now i want to prepare a json with combination of three jsons. Tnitial 3 JSON's are proper, those doesn't have any escape characters.

Comment: decimal will be removed by proper POJO class is used instead of Object

Comment: Thank you Braj, i cant the prepare the POJO as the json data has more than 100 fields. I have 3 JSONs, i need to combine them to form a final JSON string and just need to pass on.

Comment: If the original issue is solved then please post a separate question with complete details and samples.

Comment: Thanks Braj ... The initial problem i am posted also the same. I have 3 JSONs and need to combine them into a single JSON and need to pass it .

Comment: As I told you share your json strings.

Comment: Is it the same JSON string that you want 3 times to combine in single JSON.

Comment: Hi Brag, Sorry for late reply. Neither i don't have POJO nor i can't create POJO (because JSON contains more that 100 fields). Mongo DB will give me 3 JSON Strings, where each JSON is contains 100+ fields, i want to return the combined JSON to the client. All 3 are different JSON's and i am not sure of the length and fields in those JSONs.