# Building a json through Gson

Tags: java, json, oop, gson

i have here a little project that getting data from a table and return it as json with the use of json, but the json its returning seems to be a string. it has back slash, can someone knows what it causes.

```
Result result = new Result();
        result.responseCode = "00";
        result.responseMessage = "Successful";

        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.serializeNulls().create();

        String x = "x";
        String name="",address ="",msisdn="",email="";
        Details details = new Details();
        for(DataRow dr : drw_){

            name = dr.get("NAME").toString();
            details.name = name;

            address = dr.get("ADDRESS").toString();
            details.address = address;

            msisdn = dr.get("CONTACTNUMBER").toString();
            details.msisdn = msisdn;

            email = dr.get("EMAIL").toString();
            details.email = email;

            gson.toJson(details);

            result.detailsList.add(gson.toJson(details));

        }
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(details));
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(result));
```

Sample output:

```
{"responseMessage":"Successful",
 "responseCode":"00",
  "detailsList":["{\"name\":\"name1\",
               \"address\":\"address st 1\",
               \"msisdn\":\"09211231234\",
               \"email\":\"email@someweb.com\"}"
            ,"{
               \"name\":\"testname\",
               \"address\":\"testadress st 1 CITY\",
               \"msisdn\":\"+639171234567\",
               \"email\":\"myemail@someweb.com\"}
            "]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{"responseMessage":"Successful",
"responseCode":"00",
"detailsList":[{"name":"name1",
               "address":"address st 1",
               "msisdn":"09211231234",
               "email":"email@someweb.com"}
            ,{
               "name":"testname",
               "address":"testadress st 1 CITY",
               "msisdn":"+639171234567",
               "email":"myemail@someweb.com"}
 ]}
```

Comment: i have here a little project that getting data from a table and return it as json with the use of Gson*, but the json it was returning seems to be a string. it has back slash, can someone knows what it causes.

Sorry for errors.

Comment: Your `detailsList` seems to be a list of Strings, please post `Result` class.

Comment: My another [POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713687/gson-how-to-convert-object-which-itself-contains-json-to-json/24713733#24713733) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are building a json where each element of `detailList` list field is an string containing the string representation of other Json previously generated:

```
result.detailsList.add(gson.toJson(details));
```

Your `detailsList` seems to be a list of strings.
`detailsList` should be a collection of a class `Details` objects instead of `Strings`.

This way, the line above should be changed to:

```
result.detailsList.add(details);
```

Otherwise, which is happening to you now, you are encoding strings containing quotes thus, these quotes are being encoding with escape characters.

Comment: the result.detailsList.add(details) gives me an error, may i just try the replace string or just look for another way. by the way thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @mochickie  Which type `detailsList` is of? If it is something like `List<Details>`, can you post `Details` class? I would not recommend you to use replacements because, eventually, you may want to add new levels to your data hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The Slashes are escape because of the " value. This can break a string. For example

```
String x = "{"name":"name1"}" // Not a valid string

String x = "{\"name\":\"name1\"}" // Valid string
```

Try it out and the compiler will show you the errors.

Comment: public class Result {
 public String responseMessage;
 public String responseCode;
 List <String> detailsList = new ArrayList<String>();
}
    public class Details {

 public String name;
 public String address;
 public String msisdn;
 public String email;
}

Answer (score 0):

You are converting it to gson twice.. So the second parsing escapes the double quotes. Try like this

```
    Result result = new Result();
    result.responseCode = "00";
    result.responseMessage = "Successful";

    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = builder.serializeNulls().create();

    String x = "x";
    String name="",address ="",msisdn="",email="";
    Details details = new Details();
    for(DataRow dr : drw_){

        name = dr.get("NAME").toString();
        details.name = name;

        address = dr.get("ADDRESS").toString();
        details.address = address;

        msisdn = dr.get("CONTACTNUMBER").toString();
        details.msisdn = msisdn;

        email = dr.get("EMAIL").toString();
        details.email = email;

        result.detailsList.add(details);

    }
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(details));
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try: `result.detailsList.add(details);`? You should let JSON serialize everything in one go and not put a JSON String inside another object.